# What is the best way to convert an array of bytes into a json string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

In Javascript I would do it like that:

```
    const _data = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 77, 100]);
    
    const s = '[' + _data.join(',') + ']';

    console.log(s);

    > [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,100]
```

Added the solution from SomeDude:

```
    byte[] b = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,77};
    s = Arrays.toString(b);
    System.out.println(s);

    > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 77]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method:

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5};
String s = Arrays.toString(b);
```

Or

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
 for ( int i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ) sb.append(String.valueOf(b[i]) + ",");
 sb.append("]");
 String s = sb.toString();
```

Or with streams if you have an array of boxed bytes like:

```
Byte[] B = new Byte[]{1,2,3,4,5};
String s = "[" + Stream.of(B).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]";
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: yep. I was wondering if there is a possibility to do it without the conversion in a loop; the code is a bit chunky compared to JS - 4 lines of code vs. one. And the need of an extra array. But this seem to be unavoidable.

Comment: Ahh! Arrays.toString. This is it. the 'json style' brackets are already included, so the final code is like this:

        byte[] b = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,77};
        s = Arrays.toString(b);
        System.out.println(s);

Comment: @Gisela yes right forgot that..no need to add "[,]"

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the *best* way, but this is *a* way:

```
final var data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 77, 100 };

final var s = "[" + 
    IntStream.range(0, data.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> Byte.toString(data[i]))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) +
    "]";

System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: unfortunately not. - Arrays.stream cannot handle byte arrays

Comment: @Gisela: right - didn't notice that they array was byte data :(

Comment: Updated my answer to work with byte array